# Angular 2/4/5/6 - Transforming the innerHTML of a custom component on its component class side

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, material-design

I want to make the following basic component: `card.component` to take whatever the user defines on it's `innerHTML` into its component class so it can transform it and display it on its template.

This is how the user is going to use this component:

```
<app-card>hello world, this is a sample text</app-card>
```

Here you have a base project on [StackBlitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmdpgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcard%2Fcard.component.ts) which you can fork to make it work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmdpgh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fcard%2Fcard.component.ts

Here you have a preview of the code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-card',
    templateUrl: 'card.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ 'card.component.css' ],
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  private content: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    // please, override this to get the real innerHTML on: 'app.component.html'
    let innerHTML = 'testing';
    this.content = CardComponent.complexStrTransform(innerHTML);
  }
  private static complexStrTransform(str: string): string {
    // complex transformations here
    let result = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      let c = str[i];
      result += c;
      result += c.toUpperCase();
      result += '|';
    }
    result = '!!!' + result + '!!!';
    return result;
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        {{content}}
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

where on the location of: `{{content}}` the component should display the result of: `complexStrTransform(...)`.

I have seen on some places that it is possible to use: `<ng-content></ng-content>` to specify on the component's template where you want to put the `innerHTML` but I think that's not the best bet here because I need to transform that `innerHTML` with very complex changes that can be done only on the component class.

Any suggestions?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly this is what you need, But I tried to write a small solution to do a general component interaction with your example,

1. In your card component,

Add an input which we can use later from the main app component,

```
 @Input('complexInput') complexInputContent: string;
```

Then Initiate the innerHTML to the added global input,

```
 let innerHTML = this.complexInputContent;
```

2. Update your app component as below,

```html
<app-card  [complexInput]="contentDiv.innerText">


<div #contentDiv contenteditable="true" >

hello world, this is a sample text

</div>


</app-card>
```

This is the working solution (Preview): https://angular-k5wjbp.stackblitz.io/

Editable code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k5wjbp

References: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: that was a good try, but I'm looking for something simpler, like: `<app-card>hello world, this is a sample text</app-card>`

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer by Dilusha gets part of the job done. The other part is to implement your transform function as a pipe, and use a bit of DOM trickery. [Here is is on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c2g3hi).

First, rework your transform function as a Pipe (and refactor the component):

```
import { Component, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: 'card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['card.component.css'],
})
export class CardComponent { }

@Pipe({ name: 'complexStr' })
export class ComplexStrPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(str: string): string {
    // complex transformations here
    let result = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      let c = str[i];
      result += c;
      result += c.toUpperCase();
      result += '|';
    }
    result = '!!!' + result + '!!!';
    return result;
  }
}
```

Next, add the `ng-content` tag to your component so users can simply insert content. At the same time, hide that with style using `display: none` and assign it a template reference variable so that your component can access it and display it using the pipe:

```
<mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        {{inner.innerText | complexStr}}
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
        <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
<div #inner style="display: none">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Now your component works as desired:

```
<app-card>hello world, this is a sample text</app-card>
```

This is a bit of a hack obviously, as the original user content still exists in the DOM. But it gets the job done quite efficiently.